# When I iterate data from an array using for loop I get only the last string and the above strings are overlapped

Tags: objective-c

```
Name *myName = [[Name alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<[nameArray count]; i++) {
        myName.name = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", myName.name);
        self.lblName.text = myName.name;
    }
```

where, 
          `Name` is `NSObject` Class.
          `nameArray` is a variable where I stored array objects.
          `self.lblName` is the outlet connected on view controller.

Question is that, when I log `myName.name` it gives all data but when I tried to show this data in `viewController(self.lblName.text)` it gives the last object of an array.

How could I solve this problem? Can anyone explain me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the names in one label you should append, not assign. What you do right now is just displaying the last object.

```
self.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.lblName.text, myName.name];
```

Maybe the better way to do so is to have string variable and use it later on to present it in UILabel:

```
Name *myName = [[Name alloc] init];
NSString *stringForLabel = @"";
for (int i = 0; i<[nameArray count]; i++) {
    myName.name = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", myName.name);
    stringForLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",stringForLabel ,myName.name ];
}
self.lblName.text = stringForLabel;
```